# Failure in Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle

There is an issue with my stored procedure.
It fails in the below case

```
cntmismatch NUMBER;

SELECT COUNT(keyvalue) INTO cntmismatch 
FROM tbl_temp GROUP BY keyvalue HAVING count(keyvalue) > 1
```

When there is no data for the above criteria , it fails

I even tried using

```
SELECT NVL(COUNT(keyvalue),0) INTO cntmismatch 
FROM tbl_temp GROUP BY keyvalue HAVING count(keyvalue) > 1
```

But still it retuns me null here and proc fails

Comment: Please explain what problem you are trying to solve.  As you can see from the answers, there are a number of possible solutions but they address different issues.  As a rule it is usually better to tell us the business rules you're trying to implement rather than expecting us to guess them from some failing code.

Answer (score 3):

The query:

```
SELECT COUNT(keyvalue) INTO cntmismatch FROM tbl_temp GROUP BY keyvalue
```

... would attempt to return one row into `cntmismatch` for every `keyvalue`, which would fail with `no_data_found` if the table was empty and with `too_many_rows` if there was more than one `keyvalue`.

Adding:

```
HAVING count(keyvalue) > 1
```

... means it will only return a value for any `keyvalue` with more than one entry, clearly, so now you'll get `no_data_found` if the table is empty or if no `keyvalue` appears twice; and `too_many_rows` if more than one `keyvalue` has duplicates. It will only work if you have exactly one `keyvalue` that has duplicates.

You haven't shown the rest of your logic, but presumably you're doing something based on that returned value, in which case - if there was only one `keyvalue`, which is unlikely - you could leave out the `HAVING` clause and just test the value:

```
SELECT COUNT(keyvalue) INTO cntmismatch FROM tbl_temp GROUP BY keyvalue;
IF cntmismatch > 1 THEN
   ... -- some processing
END IF:
```

But at best, all it's telling you is whether there is any `keyvalue` that appears more than once; it doesn't tell you what they `keyvalue` is, and still can't cope with there being more than one.

If you want to retrieve all the values that have more than one matching row and do something with them then you could use a cursor:

```
FOR dup_keyvalues IN (SELECT keyvalue, COUNT(*) AS cnt 
    FROM tbl_temp GROUP BY keyvalue HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) LOOP
    ... - some processing, e.g.
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('keyvalue ' || dup_keyvalues.keyvalue
        || ' has ' || dup_keyvalues.cnt || ' matches');
    ...
END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count how many values of `keyvalue` occur more than once you need to use a sub-select:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cntmismatch 
FROM
( SELECT keyvalue, count(*) FROM tbl_temp GROUP BY keyvalue HAVING count(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should simply catch and handle the exception in your code.
In your case, you will get a NO_DATA_FOUND exception.

Below you will find an example.

```
PROCEDURE count_mismatch AS
  cntmismatch NUMBER;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(keyvalue) INTO cntmismatch FROM tbl_temp GROUP BY keyvalue;
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN no_data_found THEN
    cntmismatch := -1;
  END;
END
```

I argue, you don't need the HAVING clause anymore. Therefore I have removed it.
If your statement will return more than the expected 1 row, then you have to handle also the TOO_MANY_ROWS exception!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(keyvalue) INTO cntmismatch 
    FROM tbl_temp GROUP BY keyvalue HAVING count(keyvalue) > 1
EXCEPTION
  WHEN no_data_found THEN cntmismatch := 0;
END;
```